# can I start Lync 2010 client application using the Lync 2010 SDK

Tags: lync-2010

in cases where I am using Lync 2010 SDK (which depends on having the Lync 2010 client being installed and operational) in a web application and that client is closed, can I using the Lync 2010 SDK to start client application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without using Lync SDK,
Instead you can try out this

**bool isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Communicator")
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Lync")) != default(Process);
if(!isRunning)
                Process.Start("Communicator");**

May be this will be helpfull to you.

thnks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Lync setup for suppressed mode then you can call the `BeginInitialize` method on the `LyncClient` object to start up Lync in suppressed mode (aka no user interface).

This [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh379965.aspx) describes the `BeginInitialize` method.  Below is an example in C#:

```
LyncClient lyncClient = LyncClient.GetClient();

if (lyncClient.InSuppressedMode && 
    lyncClient.State == ClientState.Uninitialized)
{
  lyncClient.BeginInitialize(result => lyncClient.EndInitialize(result), 
    "Starting Lync");
}
```

Comment: what if i dont want to use suppression mode ? I still want users to be able to use Lync through its client interface ?